# Directing hostname to another computer within lan using hosts file

Tags: networking, hosts

There seem to be more questions like this, excuse me if this is similar. I want to redirect to an IP address om my server computer.

This is what I put in my hosts file on the client computer (IMac):

```
192.168.3.2:8080. dev.dev
```

It does not resolve to that IP address. Should this normally work, or do I have to do extra things?

(The IP address works in the browser).

Comment: remove the port assignment. Name resolution doesn't concern itself with TCP ports.

Comment: OK, so I will have to type that after the name in the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not specify the port in a hosts file.  The hosts file expects IP and hostname on each line.  Try removing the port, as well as the dot after the IP that I also see in your entry.

e.g.

```
192.168.3.2    dev
```

then try `http://dev:8080` in your browser to get to that host:port.  You may need to flush the cache on your client computer.  From the terminal in OSX 10.6+:

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
```

Comment: Sorry, the dot was a typo, thank you both, that should solve it. I turned the server off now, but I am gonna test it tomorrow.